# SOLR count of groups

Tags: solr, fieldcollapsing

`http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=(apposta apposta per) OR (sue prime ore al)&group=true&group.field=grouping_field&group.limit=5`

This query returns 2 groups first group has 1 document and second group has 2 documents.

In response I see count of documents(3) but there is no counts of groups.
How can I get count of groups.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `group.ngroups=true` to include the number of groups in the response.

More info  @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

Documentation -
*group.ngroups - true/false

If true, includes the number of groups that have matched the query. Default is false.*

Answer (score 5):

One comment to above answer that is 100% correct however there is extra condition!

You can **not** have:

**group.main    => 'true'**

Comment: Any other alternative solution to get group count when using group.main=true?

Comment: This is what I did to get group count but at the same time using `group.main=true`. I made 2 calls to solr. The first call will have `group.ngroups=true&rows=0`. This way we don't get any data but only the count. The second call will have `group.main=true'. Hope this helps someone.